# how to open keyboard that pushes two edittext and does not cover the edittext

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

If I have layout that contains two editText and a button. when i press on the first edittext the keyboard is been visible and the keyboard covers the second edit text ,if i press on the second edittext the keyboard pushes both of the edittext and i can see them both, 
comment:
 on the manifest the activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
please advise